# Regex for a list

Tags: regex, tcl

I have file names so I just want to select only  one without ( - )

```
6.6.482.R2
6.6.482.R2-KAob.ios
6.6.482.R2-Kaw.ios
6.6.482.R2-Ksware.ios
6.6.482.R2-KCyb.ios
6.6.482.R2-software.blm
6.7.142.R1
6.7.142.R1-KAob.ios
6.7.142.R1-Kaw.ios
6.7.142.R1-Ksware.ios
6.7.142.R1-KCyb.ios
6.7.142.R1-software.blm
```

I just want to extract only these two line

```
6.6.482.R2
6.7.142.R1
```

Regards

Comment: Within the given data set, the regular expression `{\d$}` will indicate the lines you want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly you want only the prefixes. I assume your images end with

```
"-something"
lsort -unique [regexp -all -inline -- {alm-[^ -]*} $data]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% set x {
alm-6.6.482.R2
alm-6.6.482.R2-KAob.ios
alm-6.6.482.R2-Kaw.ios
alm-6.6.482.R2-Ksware.ios
alm-6.6.482.R2-KCyb.ios
alm-6.6.482.R2-software.blm
alm-6.7.142.R1
alm-6.7.142.R1-KAob.ios
alm-6.7.142.R1-Kaw.ios
alm-6.7.142.R1-Ksware.ios
alm-6.7.142.R1-KCyb.ios
alm-6.7.142.R1-software.blm
}
alm-6.6.482.R2
alm-6.6.482.R2-KAob.ios
alm-6.6.482.R2-Kaw.ios
alm-6.6.482.R2-Ksware.ios
alm-6.6.482.R2-KCyb.ios
alm-6.6.482.R2-software.blm
alm-6.7.142.R1
alm-6.7.142.R1-KAob.ios
alm-6.7.142.R1-Kaw.ios
alm-6.7.142.R1-Ksware.ios
alm-6.7.142.R1-KCyb.ios
alm-6.7.142.R1-software.blm
% lsort -unique [regsub -all -line {alm-([^ -]+).*} $x {\1}]
6.6.482.R2 6.7.142.R1
%
```